# Open SVN diffs in meld tabs, not in serial

Tags: svn, tabs, diff, meld

I'm using `meld` to look through differences between revisions as following:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd='meld' -r HEAD
```

This method opens diffs in serial and I cannot see all differences simultaneously. However, it'd be more convinient to open all the diffs in tabs of the `meld`. How to gain it?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. Solved it this way:

**meldn.sh** - runs `meld` with `-n` key (didn't find a way to pass command with keys to `--svn-diff`)

```
#!/bin/bash

left="$6"
right="$7"

meld -n "$left" "$right"
```

**svn-diff.sh** - runs `svn diff` for each file in background (`&` sign), so all the diffs are opened at once

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"
do
    svn diff --diff-cmd=/home/user/meldn.sh $file &
done
```

Get diffs for 3 files in 3 tabs:

```
/home/user/svn-diff.sh file1 file2 file3
```